# Data recover hardware raid vs zfs pool

Tags: raid, zfs, hardware-raid

How does one recover data after disk failure in zfs software raid or Synology hw raid?

Is it easier , less corruption in one or other ?
Is one more susceptible to write corruptions than other ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

There probably isn't a more specific answer without more specific information about the anticipated hardware setup, the RAID level, the quantity and type of disks, the reason for a failure, etc...

I'd usually take a well-designed ZFS solution over a consumer NAS solution, but again, the details matter.